# Search Bar not showing on Tab Bar Screen Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I have a project where one of the tab view controllers will have a search bar. I can get the search bar to show until I put the view controller inside of a tab bar controller.

```
    import UIKit

class MasterController: UIViewController {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candies"
        definesPresentationContext = true
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Custom"
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }


}

extension MasterController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to embed the view controlled in a navigation controller.